# Zeroing the elements of an array using a particular set of rules?

Tags: algorithm

Given n numbers, you can perform the following operation any number of times : Choose any subset of the numbers, none of which are 0. Decrement the numbers in the subset by 1, and increment the numbers not in the subset by K.

Is it possible to perform operations such that all numbers except one of them become 0 ?

Input :
The first line contains the number of test cases T. 2*T lines follow, 2 for each case. The first line of a test case contains the numbers n and K. The next line contains n numbers, a_1...a_n.

Output :
Output T lines, one corresponding to each test case. For a test case, output "YES" if there is a sequence of operations as described, and "NO" otherwise.

Sample Input :

```
3
2 1
10 10
3 2
1 2 2
3 2
1 2 3
```

Sample Output :

```
YES
YES
NO
```

Constraints :

```
1 <= T <= 1000
2 <= n <= 100
1 <= K <= 10
0 <= a_i <= 1000
```

I have got my solution accepted  with the following algorithm---

```
a[i] is value in ith cell
n[i] is number of times it is selected in subset
T is total number of times the operation is done

=> a[i] - n[i] + (T - n[i])*K = 0 for all except 1
=> a[i]= n[i] (K+1) -TK 
=> a[i] = (K+1)(n[i]-T) + T
```

Hence remainder should be same for all a[i] except 1(which will become zero) and T when divided by K+1. My doubt is this condition is necessary, but how is it sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### STEP 1

Imagine a move consisting of:

1. Choose a subset A consisting of all numbers where a[i]>=K+1
2. Choose a subset consisting of the entire set K times

Numbers in the subset A will be decremented K+1 times, while numbers outside the set A will stay the same (increased by K, then decremented K times).

Repeat this move until all numbers are less than K+1.

This step will change the numbers to become their residue modulo K+1.

### STEP 2

Now suppose all the numbers are the same (except for 1).

We can now choose a subset consisting of the entire set (except for the odd one out).

This reduces all the numbers by 1 (except for the odd one out).  Repeat this choice until we have reduced all the way to 0.

### Conclusion

So if all numbers (except one) have the same residue modulo K+1, we can use step 1 to reduce them all to the same level, and then step 2 to reduce the common level down to 0.